# Are you going to SDL Innovate 2015 (San Francisco)?

Tags: discussion, innovate

As most of you know, every year SDL organizes a series of "SDL Innovate" events around the world, and this year is no exception - we're covering Amsterdam, London, San Francisco, Sydney and Tokyo.

What is different this year though is that we added a "Technical Track" to Innovate San Francisco, as - if you've been at Innovate before - these tend to be very marketing-focused events and usually just brush on topics that you could be interested on (at most you would get a roadmap overview).

So, what are we doing this year, and primarily, do you think this is enough?

First - check the agendas:

- [Developer Day](http://www.sdl.com/innovate/sanfran/agenda/preconference-day/developer-day.html)
- [Training Sessions](http://www.sdl.com/innovate/sanfran/agenda/preconference-day/introductory-training.html)
- [CX 101](http://www.sdl.com/innovate/sanfran/agenda/preconference-day/cx101.html)

Lots of known names in that Dev Day agenda, which by itself could be enough to get you thinking about going. Also lots of opportunities to network and learn about other SDL products you may be interested in. And, last but not least, **free training**!

This is the first time we're adding this type of content to our events, and I really want it to be a massive success so that it's not optional for next year - and perhaps we can even extend it to other Innovate Sessions, beyond San Francisco.

So, here's my question: Is this enough to get YOU to attend SDL Innovate?

**EDIT April 13**

We're now 4 weeks away from this event, and momentum is building up. We still have some places available for those willing to come and learn from the community.

Answer (score 2):

I can't repeat this tweet enough ;o):

> [‏@sdlinnovate](https://twitter.com/sdlinnovate)
>   Learn from [@DJBartK](https://twitter.com/djbartk) in [#SanFran](https://twitter.com/hashtag/SanFran?src=hash) this May http://bit.ly/1b5eWXF

https://twitter.com/sdlinnovate/status/578245754587860993

By the way, there is still a [free pass](https://community.sdl.com/developers/innovate_2015_developertech_days_11-13_may_san_francisco/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/10/win-a-free-pass-for-innovate-2015) up for grabs over at our [community site](https://community.sdl.com/developers/innovate_2015_developertech_days_11-13_may_san_francisco/b/weblog/archive/2015/02/10/win-a-free-pass-for-innovate-2015).

And there are also still three slots open for the lightning talks at the [developer day](http://www.sdl.com/innovate/sanfran/agenda/preconference-day/developer-day.html), drop me a message (or comment here) if you would like to come on stage.

Answer (score 2):

For all of you that made it to San Francisco (we had nearly 300 people in the Developer Day!) **THANK YOU**!

We had some really high quality sessions and a very inspiring Hackathon day. I think we're in good shape to continue promoting the developer community and have more of these events. I am sure Bart Koopman agrees.